# How to separate an array of hashes into different arrays if a key is equal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

I've got an array of hashes in the following form:

```
{"user_id"=>2, "user_name"=>"Pepo", "beneficiary_document"=>"43991028", "calification_by_qualifier"=>5.0}
{"user_id"=>2, "user_name"=>"Pepo", "beneficiary_document"=>"71730550", "calification_by_qualifier"=>3.8499999999999996}
{"user_id"=>3, "user_name"=>"Carlos", "beneficiary_document"=>"43991028", "calification_by_qualifier"=>0.0}
{"user_id"=>3, "user_name"=>"Carlos", "beneficiary_document"=>"71730550", "calification_by_qualifier"=>3.4}
```

basically i want to separate that array into arrays that contain the same value for the key `beneficiary_document`, so for this example i'd expect two arrays, one containing:

```
{"user_id"=>2, "user_name"=>"Pepo", "beneficiary_document"=>"43991028", "calification_by_qualifier"=>5.0}
{"user_id"=>3, "user_name"=>"Carlos", "beneficiary_document"=>"43991028", "calification_by_qualifier"=>0.0}
```

and another one containing

```
{"user_id"=>3, "user_name"=>"Carlos", "beneficiary_document"=>"71730550", "calification_by_qualifier"=>3.4}
{"user_id"=>2, "user_name"=>"Pepo", "beneficiary_document"=>"71730550", "calification_by_qualifier"=>3.8499999999999996}
```

How can i grant this?

Thanks a lot for reading.

Comment: http://blog.jayfields.com/2008/03/ruby-inject.html

Comment: When you give an example all of your inputs and outputs should be valid Ruby objects. (Some readers will downvote if they are not.) That means you should write `[{...},.., {...}]`. Moreover, it is helpful to assign a variable to each input (e.g., `arr = [{ "user_id"=>2,..},...{ "user_id"=>3,...}]`. That way, readers can refer to those variables in answers and comments without having to define them. It's also helpful to pare down examples to their bare essentials, and use short names for keys and values (in part to avoid the need for readers to scroll horizontally to read your code).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given:

```
tst=[
{"user_id"=>2, "user_name"=>"Pepo", "beneficiary_document"=>"43991028", "calification_by_qualifier"=>5.0}, 
{"user_id"=>2, "user_name"=>"Pepo", "beneficiary_document"=>"71730550", "calification_by_qualifier"=>3.84},
{"user_id"=>3, "user_name"=>"Carlos", "beneficiary_document"=>"43991028", "calification_by_qualifier"=>0.0}, 
{"user_id"=>3, "user_name"=>"Carlos", "beneficiary_document"=>"71730550", "calification_by_qualifier"=>3.4}
]
```

You can use [.group_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) to get a hash of elements by key. In this case, use the key `["beneficiary_document"]` passed to the block and you will get a hash of arrays by that key -- two in this case.

You can do:

```
tst.group_by { |h| h["beneficiary_document"] }
# {"43991028"=>[{"user_id"=>2, "user_name"=>"Pepo", "beneficiary_document"=>"43991028", "calification_by_qualifier"=>5.0}, {"user_id"=>3, "user_name"=>"Carlos", "beneficiary_document"=>"43991028", "calification_by_qualifier"=>0.0}], "71730550"=>[{"user_id"=>2, "user_name"=>"Pepo", "beneficiary_document"=>"71730550", "calification_by_qualifier"=>3.84}, {"user_id"=>3, "user_name"=>"Carlos", "beneficiary_document"=>"71730550", "calification_by_qualifier"=>3.4}]}
```

To see it *pretty printed*:

```
require "pp"
PP.pp(tst.group_by {|h| h["beneficiary_document"] },$>,120)
{"43991028"=>
  [{"user_id"=>2, "user_name"=>"Pepo", "beneficiary_document"=>"43991028", "calification_by_qualifier"=>5.0},
   {"user_id"=>3, "user_name"=>"Carlos", "beneficiary_document"=>"43991028", "calification_by_qualifier"=>0.0}],
 "71730550"=>
  [{"user_id"=>2, "user_name"=>"Pepo", "beneficiary_document"=>"71730550", "calification_by_qualifier"=>3.84},
   {"user_id"=>3, "user_name"=>"Carlos", "beneficiary_document"=>"71730550", "calification_by_qualifier"=>3.4}]}
```

You can also achieve the same result with a hash that returns an array as a [default procedure](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc), then call `.map` over `tst` and push the hash into the array by that key:

```
h=Hash.new { |h,k| h[k]=[] }
tst.map { |eh| h[eh["beneficiary_document"]].push(eh) }
```

Or, combine that into a single statement:

```
tst.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k]=[] }) { |g,h|
    h[g["beneficiary_document"]].push(g)}
```

All three methods create identical hashes. The first, `.group_by`, is the easiest.

Comment: So much better than where I was headed that I had to delete mine. Nice!

Answer (score 3):

Here are three ways to obtain the desired result by constructing a hash and then extracting the values.

```
arr = [{"id"=>2, "name"=>"Pepo",   "doc"=>"43991028", "cal"=>5.0}, 
       {"id"=>2, "name"=>"Pepo",   "doc"=>"71730550", "cal"=>3.8},
       {"id"=>3, "name"=>"Carlos", "doc"=>"43991028", "cal"=>0.0},
       {"id"=>3, "name"=>"Carlos", "doc"=>"71730550", "cal"=>3.4}]
```

**#1**

This uses the form of [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) that includes a block that is invoked when `h[k]` is executed, for a hash `h` that has no key `k`.

```
arr.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k]=[] }) { |g,h| h[g["doc"]] << g }.
    values
  #=> [[{"id"=>2, "name"=>"Pepo", "doc"=>"43991028", "cal"=>5.0},
  #     {"id"=>3, "name"=>"Carlos", "doc"=>"43991028", "cal"=>0.0}],
  #    [{"id"=>2, "name"=>"Pepo", "doc"=>"71730550", "cal"=>3.8},
  #     {"id"=>3, "name"=>"Carlos", "doc"=>"71730550", "cal"=>3.4}]]
```

**#2**

This is equivalent to #1.

```
arr.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| (h[g["doc"]] ||= []) << g }.
    values
```

**#3**

This uses the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that employs a block (here `{ |_,o,n| o+n }`) to determine the value of keys that are present in both hashes being merged. See the doc for the definitions of the three variables of the value-determining block.

```
arr.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h.update(g["doc"]=>[g]) { |_,o,n| o+n } }.
    values
```

Comment: The first two are genuinely interesting. The third produces `{nil=>[original list]}` because there are no keys in the default hash.

Comment: @dawg, please double-check #3. It does not use a default hash.

Comment: I have a tiny script with your example `arr` and then I cut and paste your #1, #2, #3. First two create the correct output; #3: `{nil=>[{"id"=>2, "name"=>"Pepo", "doc"=>"43991028", "cal"=>5.0}, {"id"=>2, "name"=>"Pepo", "doc"=>"71730550", "cal"=>3.8}, {"id"=>3, "name"=>"Carlos", "doc"=>"43991028", "cal"=>0.0}, {"id"=>3, "name"=>"Carlos", "doc"=>"71730550", "cal"=>3.4}]}`.  Ruby 2.4.1. I removed the `.values` part on all three...

Comment: [Here is a demo](https://repl.it/JS9S/0) The original Array is duplicated because each element is being appended to a key `nil`

Comment: The *correct* version #3 is `arr.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h.update(g["doc"]=>[g]) { |_,o,n| o+n } }`. [DEMO](https://repl.it/JS9S/1)

Comment: @dawg, my understanding is that an array of five hashes is to be converted to two arrays, `a1` and `a2`, with `a1` containing two of the five hashes and `a3` containing the other three (which is why `.value` is required). My return value is the array `[a1, a2]`.  I just re-tested each of the three calculations. They all return the value I show for #1.

Comment: Did you look at the link? Your example array and your code -- #3 fails.

Comment: The issue I am pointing out is `h.update(h[g["doc"]]=>[g])` vs `h.update(g["doc"]=>[g])` The first produces `nil` the second produces the common key for the initial hash and the update.

Comment: I am not commenting on the `.values` part. I assumed the OP could figure that part out himself. ;-) I am curious how you possibly could get the same value for #3 as #1. The Ruby interpreter link clearly shows that it is different.

Comment: @Dawg, thanks. I fixed #3. After you comments I looked over my code several times but could not spot the difference between `h[g["doc"]]=>[g]` and `g["doc"]=>[g]`. :-) Also, I clearly wasn't careful enough when comparing the return value from my former #3 with that of #1.

Comment: My eyes were crossing trying to figure it out as well. Since I am just learning Ruby, I was determined to find out what the issue was...

Comment: Such determination will return big dividends.

Comment: Thats what I keep telling my kids. ;-) Hope it sinks in.